# Try/Catch not working with exception name

Tags: python, try-catch

I'm unable to catch what appears to be a ConnectionError. This does not work:

```
except ConnectionError:
            return {
                'error_status_code': 500,
                'error_message': "Activity Stream connection failed",
            }
```

But this does work:

```
except Exception as e:
        if(e.__class__.__name__ == 'ConnectionError'):
            return {
                'error_status_code': 500,
                'error_message': "Activity Stream connection failed",
            }
        else:
            raise e
```

When printing e using pdb.set_trace(), I get:

`ConnectionError(MaxRetryError("HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x10f00e278>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',))",),)`

Suggesting that it is a ConnectionError. I've also tried to catch MaxRetryError and NewConnectionError with no effect.

Thanks

Comment: just an assumption: you may have imported (and used) the incorrect `ConnectionError`

Comment: As @Tryph mentioned, are you sure it couldn't be for instance a `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError` ?

Comment: Great job! That solved it. Sneaky!